# notepad++ Export Built-in languages

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting

I just wanted to change the coloring settings for the Java language a little bit. So can I kinda export the Java language just to import it again? So I can change some things and save it then as a custom language.

regards, TPRammus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Settings > Style Configurator` you can change the default colors for different syntax types (eg. keywords) for all languages, as well as the colors used by specific languages. This might be enough for what you want.

Otherwise, I dont believe that you want to create a custom language and instead want a custom theme. [Configuration entry from the NP++ Wiki.](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Configuration_Files#Syntax_highlighting_themes) The summary is that themes are stored in `%APPDATA%\Notepad++\Themes` and are fairly simple XML files. They can be imported under `Settings > Import > Import theme`.